# Set a tr id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change a tr's id in jQuery. I have the html in a variable.

I am trying to do this way but it is not working.

```
var xHTML = $('#td').html();
xHTML = $(xHTML).find('#id').attr('id', 'id' + cnt).end().map(function () {
    return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join('');
```

Comment: Please also try with "prop('id', 'id'+cnt)"

Comment: Can you please set up a jsfiddle with all your code?

Comment: what is `#td` and `#id` ??? or post the markup.

Comment: why not just do `$('#td').find('#id')` rather than getting the html and then converting that into a jquery object

Comment: jsfiddle please. It'll be easier for everyone to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Please provide your HTML structure

Comment: You already know the `id` of the `tr`, so just target it directly: `$('#id').prop('id', 'id' + cnt);` or am I missing something?

Comment: I have a feeling there are duplicate ID's in OPs html markup

Comment: Why does this question have 3 up-votes?

Comment: @oGeez I was wondering the same thing

Comment: @billyonecan I'm glad, I genuinely thought I was missing something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/html/

The `html()` function gets the html string.  Then when you pass it in to `$()`, JQuery is creating html elements that are the same as your content and are not part of the DOM.

Instead you should just use:

```
$('#id').prop('id', 'id' + cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see your HTML structure, but assuming you start off from some `td` element:

```
$('#someTd').closest('tr').attr('id', 'id' + cnt);
```